# Can't set width of <td> elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <table class="table table-hover custom-table table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <draggable v-model="tableHeaders" :options="{ handle: '.handle' }">
          <th class="handle" v-for="header in tableHeaders" :key="header">
            {{ header }}
          </th>
        </draggable>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <draggable
          v-model="tableData"
          :options="{
            handle: '.handle',
            ghostClass: 'ghost-class',
            chosenClass: 'chosen-class',
          }"
        >
          <tr v-for="item in tableData" :key="item.id" class="handle">
            <td v-for="header in tableHeaders">
              {{ item[header.toLowerCase()] }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </draggable>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
th:hover,
td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ghost-class {
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.chosen-class {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.custom-table td,
.custom-table th {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 5%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.custom-table .handle {
  cursor: move;
}

.custom-table .handle:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover {
  background-color: #323346;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover td,
.custom-table .handle:hover th {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover .chosen-class,
.custom-table .handle:hover .ghost-class {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover .chosen-class {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.custom-table .handle:hover .ghost-class {
  cursor: move;
}
</style>
```

I cannot set the width of the td elements - even if i try to directly set width on the td element I cannot do it. There are twenty items within the grid table and i have the headers set to 5% and im trying to get the td elements set to 5%

I tried to change the width of the td elements but im finding i cannot change the data cells width

How do i change the width of the  cells?

Comment: Does it work as inline styling or if you use `<style scoped>`? You may have other css rules elsewhere affecting them.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to setting the width of COLUMNS is to style the **TH**

```
th:nth-child(1) {width:5%;}

th:nth-child(4) {width:10%;}
```

To set the height of ROWS you style the **TR**

```
tr:nth-child(2) {height:80px;}

tr:nth-child(6) {height:50px;}
```

And so forth...